# Intersection of two dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, intersection

I am trying to keep only the columns AND rows of two dataframes that are common to both of them. Put differently, I am trying to filter for the column names and the elements of one column (which contains the dates):

I tried this so far (from one of the forums here):

```
common_cols <- intersect(colnames(df_tot), colnames(roe))
common_rows <-as.Date(intersect(df_tot$dates, roe$dates), origin = "1970-01-01")

df_tot[common_rows, common_cols]
roe[common_rows, common_cols]
```

But the dataset contains only NAs. Can someone help?

I tried a different approach, which worked now:

```
row.names(df_tot)<-df_tot$dates
row.names(roe)<-roe$dates

common_cols <- intersect(colnames(df_tot), colnames(roe))
common_rows <- intersect(rownames(df_tot), rownames(roe))

df_tot[common_rows, common_cols]
roe[common_rows, common_cols]
```

Comment: Please provide example objects `df_tot` and `roe`.

Comment: Given that your `common_rows` vector contains a set of dates, perhaps you should be doing `df_tot[df_tot$dates %in% common_rows, common_cols]` instead. The first argument will look at the dates in `df_tot` and capture only those rows whose dates exist in `common_rows`.

Comment: It turned out, I had some typo in there. What I did not is this:row.names(returns)<-returns$dates
row.names(fcf)<-fcf$dates


common_cols <- intersect(colnames(returns), colnames(fcf))
common_rows <- intersect(rownames(returns), rownames(fcf))

df_tot<-rbind(
  returns[common_rows, common_cols], 
  fcf[common_rows, common_cols]
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made up some reproducible example data:

```
data(iris)

df_tot <- iris
roe    <- iris

colnames(roe) <- c("nonmatching.example", colnames(roe)[2:ncol(roe)])
roe$dates     <- seq(as.Date("1910/1/1"), by=1, length.out = nrow(roe))

df_tot$dates <- seq(as.Date("1910/3/1"), by=1, length.out = nrow(df_tot))


common_cols <- intersect(colnames(df_tot), colnames(roe))
common_rows <- as.Date(intersect(df_tot$dates, roe$dates))

df_tot[common_rows, common_cols]
roe[common_rows, common_cols]


table(is.na(df_tot[common_rows, common_cols]))
```

> ```
> FALSE 
>   750
> ```

```
tibble::glimpse(df_tot[common_rows, common_cols]) # use head() or summary() if you don't have the library tibble
```

> ```
> Observations: 150
> Variables: 5
> $ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, 3.5, 3.8, 3.8, 3.4, 3.7, 3.6, 3.3, 3.4, 3.0, 3.4, 3.5,...
> $ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.7, 1.5, 1.7, 1.5, 1.0, 1.7, 1.9, 1.6, 1.6, 1.5,...
> $ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2,...
> $ Species      <fctr> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, se...
> $ dates        <date> 1910-03-01, 1910-03-02, 1910-03-03, 1910-03-04, 1910-03-05, 1910-03-06, 1910-03-07, 1910-03-08, 1910-03-09, 1910-03-10, 1910-03-11, 1910-0...
> ```